# In WPF how to use GridView?

Tags: wpf, listview, gridview

In WPF there is listview but no GridView control. I am familier with ASP.NET's GridView how to insert,update and delete, its events like Rowupdating, RowEditing etc. Now I want to do same things in WPF. Please provide some working example.

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the DataGrid. Here's a CodeProject article with examples and code: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/WPFDataGridExamples.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [DataGrid control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.aspx).

Comment: In my Toolbox there is noDataGrid control. I am using VS2008.

Comment: You should use VS2010, or a third-party grid package.

Answer (score 2):

Here are the examples for using [`WPF ListView`](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AddEditDeleteRows.aspx) and [`WPF DataGrid`](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=563&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1)